# How to do series connection of DC/DC converters?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am using [Traco Power TEN 5-1223](http://www.tracopower.com/products/ten5.pdf) which has +12V input and +-15V output.

I am trying to connect 4 +12V DC/DC converters in series.

How can this be done? What are the connections to be made and to what pins?

Comment: Why on earth would you do that?  What is the input to output that you are trying to get?

Comment: I am trying to get a +-60V output through the +12V input supply.

Comment: That should be your question, then.  This proposed solution will not work.  linear.com or ti.com, among others, have tools to help you build such a supply.

Comment: And why would that be so? Linear or TI mav have the requisite boost converters but the problem is I will need to extend this later to +-200V.

Comment: Well thank you guys...obviously this is a very different forum where more than technical issues "nice" manners are important. FYI...i have a masters degree in engg...ok i am more into IC design and now venturing into electronics...

Comment: so it will be really helpful if u point me to some technical doc/reference or give me a slightly technical answer than beating around the bush...

Comment: I apologize, I was wrong.  This can work, but it is probably not the right solution.  I referred you to places where you can input all of the requirements for your design, and they will spit out a workable design for you.

Comment: I would also suggest going to http://www.picoelectronics.com/index.htm  They likely have a single part that will do what you want, in a similar form factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in this case what (it appears) you want to do will work.  To be specific, you connect the inputs of the four DC-DC converters in parallel to the same power supply, and their outputs in series.  However, this is a very klunky and expensive way to get what you want.

The reason it works in this case is because these converters are *isolated*.  The datasheet says the output can float up to 1.5 kV from the input.

Stacking the output of multiple converters in series would not work if the outputs of each was referenced back to the input (non-isolated).  For example, the input and output ground might be tied together.  This would be what you get, for example, if you were to make a simple boost or buck converter with a single inductor.

Comment: Hi Olin, when you say connect the outputs in series, I understand what it means but how can it be realised in practice? For these particular converters, I connected the +ve to the -ve and so on...and tested the final output on the 1st ve and the last -ve wires but did not get the correct result. Thanks!

Comment: @Kashif: In "series" means the + output of one converter is connected to the - output of the next.  The + output of that one is connected to the - output of the next after that, etc.  Your overall output voltage is then between the + output of the last converter and the - output of the first one.

Comment: yeps...i did that...yes its working for now. i just overlooked the dual configuration..the specs was a for a single ended supply..thanks!